# alert only when the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I created a form using `html` I want to display an alert message when the form is submitted or when the form is empty. I validated all the fields using `gen_validatorv4.js` libray. I have this below code of the form

```
<form id="popout" class="form-container" name="popout" onsubmit="return submitClick();">
        <h1 class="sticky-form">Know about the admissions</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">X</button>

        <input type="text" placeholder=" Name*" id="side_name" name="side_name" ><br />

        <input type="email" placeholder="Email*" id="side_email" name="side_email" >

        <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone*" id="side_phone" name="side_phone"><br />

        <select class="branches" id="side_branches" name="side_branches" required="">
            <option selected hidden value="">Select a branch*</option>
            <option value="RCIS,Kalyan Nagar ICSE">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar ICSE</option>
            <option value="RCIS,Kalyan Nagar CBSE">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar CBSE</option>
            <option value="RCIS,Mysuru">RCIS,Mysuru</option>
            <option value="RCIS,Sarjapur">RCIS,Sarjapur</option>
            <option value="RCIS,Begur">RCIS,Begur</option>
            <option value="RCIS,MS Palya<">RCIS,MS Palya</option>
            <option value="RCIS,Chamrajpet">RCIS,Chamrajpet</option>
        </select><br />
        <select id="side_grade" class="branches" name="side_grade" required="" style="margin-top: 2px;">
            <option selected hidden value="">Select a Grade*</option>
            <option value="Play school">Play school</option>
            <option value="Nursery">Nursery</option>
            <option value="Jr.KG">Jr.KG</option>
            <option value="Sr.KG">Sr.KG</option>
            <option value="1">&#8544;</option>
            <option value="2">&#8545;</option>
            <option value="3">&#8546;</option>
            <option value="4">&#8547;</option>
            <option value="5">&#8548;</option>
            <option value="6">&#8549;</option>
            <option value="7">&#8550;</option>
            <option value="8">&#8551;</option>
            <option value="9">&#8552;</option>
            <option value="10">&#8553;</option>
            <option value="11">&#8554;</option>
            <option value="12">&#8555;</option>
        </select>

        <!-- <input type="date" placeholder="Date of Birth*" id="side_dob" name="side_dob"><br /> -->

        <input type="text" placeholder="Residing area*" id="side_address" name="side_address" ><br />

        <textarea class="text-input" type="text" id="side_message" required="" name="side_message"
            placeholder="Enter Message*" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
            <input type="button" name="side-enquiry" id="side-enquiry" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  

        <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn" name="side-enquiry" id="side-enquiry" onclick="onSubmission()">Enquire Now</button> -->
        <span id="error_message" class="text-danger" style="display: none;"></span>
        <span id="success_message" class="text-success" style="display: none;"></span>
    </form>
```

then I added this `javascript` code

```
   function submitClick(){
    if(formValidation()){
        alert("thank");
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    function formValidation(){
        flag = true;

        if(document.popout.side_name.value == "" || document.popout.side_email.value == "" || document.popout.side_phone.value == "" || document.popout.side_address.value == "" ){
            alert("Enter alphabetic characters as Name!");
      flag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

No alert is shown when the form is empty and if I fill no alert is displayed.

How to solve it?is the `javascript` code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are forget to return the `flag` in `formValidation` .And better separate function as individual .No need to declare the `formValidation` function inside the `submitClick`

```js
function submitClick() {
  if (formValidation()) {
    alert("thank");
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function formValidation() {

  flag = true;
  if (document.popout.side_name.value == "" || document.popout.side_email.value == "" || document.popout.side_phone.value == "" || document.popout.side_address.value == "") {
    alert("Enter alphabetic characters as Name!");
    flag = false;
  }
  return flag
}
```

```html
<form id="popout" class="form-container" name="popout" onsubmit="return submitClick();">
  <h1 class="sticky-form">Know about the admissions</h1>
  <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">X</button>

  <input type="text" placeholder=" Name*" id="side_name" name="side_name"><br />

  <input type="email" placeholder="Email*" id="side_email" name="side_email">

  <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone*" id="side_phone" name="side_phone"><br />

  <select class="branches" id="side_branches" name="side_branches" required="">
    <option selected hidden value="">Select a branch*</option>
    <option value="RCIS,Kalyan Nagar ICSE">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar ICSE</option>
    <option value="RCIS,Kalyan Nagar CBSE">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar CBSE</option>
    <option value="RCIS,Mysuru">RCIS,Mysuru</option>
    <option value="RCIS,Sarjapur">RCIS,Sarjapur</option>
    <option value="RCIS,Begur">RCIS,Begur</option>
    <option value="RCIS,MS Palya<">RCIS,MS Palya</option>
    <option value="RCIS,Chamrajpet">RCIS,Chamrajpet</option>
  </select><br />
  <select id="side_grade" class="branches" name="side_grade" required="" style="margin-top: 2px;">
    <option selected hidden value="">Select a Grade*</option>
    <option value="Play school">Play school</option>
    <option value="Nursery">Nursery</option>
    <option value="Jr.KG">Jr.KG</option>
    <option value="Sr.KG">Sr.KG</option>
    <option value="1">&#8544;</option>
    <option value="2">&#8545;</option>
    <option value="3">&#8546;</option>
    <option value="4">&#8547;</option>
    <option value="5">&#8548;</option>
    <option value="6">&#8549;</option>
    <option value="7">&#8550;</option>
    <option value="8">&#8551;</option>
    <option value="9">&#8552;</option>
    <option value="10">&#8553;</option>
    <option value="11">&#8554;</option>
    <option value="12">&#8555;</option>
  </select>

  <!-- <input type="date" placeholder="Date of Birth*" id="side_dob" name="side_dob"><br /> -->

  <input type="text" placeholder="Residing area*" id="side_address" name="side_address"><br />

  <textarea class="text-input" type="text" id="side_message" required="" name="side_message" placeholder="Enter Message*" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="side-enquiry" id="side-enquiry" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />

  <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn" name="side-enquiry" id="side-enquiry" onclick="onSubmission()">Enquire Now</button> -->
  <span id="error_message" class="text-danger" style="display: none;"></span>
  <span id="success_message" class="text-success" style="display: none;"></span>
</form>
```